# How to change order in the summary order?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, render

in my file phtml I have method:
     `<?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>`.

I want to change order from

1. subtotal,
2. combined order
3. shipping
4. grandtotal

to

1. subtotal,
2. combined order
3. shipping
4. grandtotal.

How to make this? I looking for xml to this, but I have not found.

Any hints?

---

This not work form me, bacuse in admin I don't have 'connected orders'

This is my method in my custom module:

```
  protected function _initTotals() {
    parent::_initTotals();
    $amount = $this->getSource()->getOrder()->getConnectedSubtotal();
    if ($amount > 0) {
        $this->addTotal(new Varien_Object(array(
            'code' => 'connection',
            'value' => $amount,
            'base_value' => $amount,
            'label' => Mage::helper('orderConnection')->__('Orders connected'),
        )));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

How to change order?

Comment: did you solve your issue or you looking for any other answer?

Comment: I am looking for solution, because change sort order in admin not help me

Comment: try to change sort order using syste,->configuration-> sakes checkouts total sort order to change order

Comment: In admin I don't have order-connected

Comment: @Miuzik, please check the question description. the order is same whichever you want to change

Answer (score 0):

In Admin Side  Go to System->Configuration->Sales

In Sales Select sub cat. sales in which you can see "checkouts total sort order" in that change the order sequence As you wish.

Do not edit in coding side it is possible in admin side without coding.

Comment: In admin I don't have order-connected